# Error in codelite installation in ubuntu 20.04 (dpendencies)

Tags: dependencies

I am getting following issues while installation of codelite in ubuntu 20.04

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

codelite : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.9 is to be installed

Depends: liblldb-14 but it is not installable

Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 12) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed

Recommends: lldb (>= 3.4) but it is not going to be installed

Recommends: nodejs

Recommends: clang-tools but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs when your system is in inconsistent state. Is it a clean Ubuntu 20.04 installation or it has foreign repos like Debian, etc?

The current legit codelite version in the repo is: codelite/focal 13.0+dfsg-1.

Check on your system with command:

```
apt search codelite
```

and see what you get there.

Comment: Full Text Search... Done
codelite/stable 16.0-2unofficial.jammy amd64
  cross-platform C/C++ RAD

codelite-dbg/stable 16.0-2unofficial.jammy amd64
  Debug symbols for CodeLite

codelite-plugins/focal 13.0+dfsg-1 amd64
  Powerful and lightweight IDE - plugins

wxcrafter/stable 2.5-1.trusty amd64
  gui generator plugin for codelite

Comment: Well, the problem seems to be with the jammy repo. Try installing codelite like this: sudo apt install codelite=13.0+dfsg-1

Comment: Thanks it installed